# How to derive the bias term in Regularized Support Vector Machine?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, machine-learning

My question is: 
How to derive $ b^* $ (optimal $ b $) when **all $ \alpha_{i} $ is $ 0 $ or $ C $**?

For a given SVM primal problem:

$$ \text{minimize } \frac{1}{2}w^{T}w + C\sum_{i=1}^{l}\xi_{i}$$
$$ \text{subject to }  y_{i}(w^{T}\phi(x_{i}) + b) \ge 1 - \xi_{i} $$
$$ \xi_{i} \ge 0 $$

I already know how to derive the dual problem:

$$ \text{min } \frac{1}{2}\alpha^{T}Q\alpha - \mathbf{1}^{T}\alpha$$
$$ \text{subject to } 0 \le \alpha_{i} \le C$$
$$ \mathbf{y}^{T}\alpha = 0 $$
$$ \text{where } Q_{ij} = y_{i} y_{j} \phi(x_{i})^{T} \phi(x_{j}) $$ 
And I know by KKT condition, we have:
$$ \alpha_{i}(1 - \xi_{i} - y_{i}(w^{T}\phi(x_i) + b)) = 0 $$
$$ \beta_{i}(-\xi_i) = 0 $$
$$ \nabla_{w} L(w, b, \xi, \alpha, \beta) = 0 \Rightarrow w = \sum_{i=1}^{l} \alpha_{i} y_{i} \phi(x_{i}) $$
$$ \nabla_{b} L(w, b, \xi, \alpha, \beta) = 0 \Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^{l}\alpha_{i} y_{i} = 0 $$
$$ \nabla_{\xi} L(w, b, \xi, \alpha, \beta) = 0 \Rightarrow C = \alpha_{i} + \beta_{i}$$

I just saw this [paper](http://disp.ee.ntu.edu.tw/~pujols/Support%20Vector%20Machine.pdf)'s 13th and 14th page, but it said just sample an $  0 \lt \alpha_{i} \lt C $ so we can find $ b $ by 
$$ \alpha_{i}(1 - \xi_{i} - y_{i}(w^{T}\phi(x_i) + b)) = 0 $$
$$ \beta_{i}(-\xi_i) = 0 $$
because $ \xi_i = 0 $ and $ 1 - \xi_{i} - y_{i}(w^{T}\phi(x_i) + b) = 0 $

**But**, what if  $\alpha_{i} $ is $ 0 $ or $ C $?

Note: I took the notation in [this slide](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/courses/optml2018/svm.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

In order to determine the bias $b$ you use

$$Y(\boldsymbol{x}) = \boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{\phi}(\boldsymbol{x})+b$$

for the support vectors for which $0< \alpha_i<C$ and $\xi_i=0$, because they lie on the boundary of the margin.

Then you will have to solve

$$y_i\left[\sum_{m\in S}\alpha_my_m\boldsymbol{\phi}^T(\boldsymbol{x}_i)\boldsymbol{\phi}(\boldsymbol{x}_m)+b\right]=1,$$

in which $S$ is the set of all indices of the support vectors for the bias $b$.

In Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning by Bishop, the author also argues that it is better to average this equation over the support vectors.

Comment: So, is $0 \lt \alpha_{i} \lt C $ guarantee to exist ? How can we prove the existence?